# How to set up a personalize web-based email (not with google app)

Tags: email, webmail

I have a humble community site running on a tiny ubuntu VPS. I need to set up and use an email like contact@mysite.com to handle my  'official'  communications.

I don't want to rely on google app emails (since it's 500 email/day limit poses an scalability issue). I know that it can be done on the vps [using postfix](http://library.linode.com/email/postfix/dovecot-mysql-ubuntu-10.04-lucid) but I prefer a web-based email, so that I don't need to use a text-based email client on the server.

I really appreciate your hints to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would recommend going with an outsourced solution; mostly because you will constantly be crashing into little issues with different ISPs who require various types of adress validations, etc.

But if you're convinced you want to go out and do it yourself...

Follow [this guide here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenWebMail) to install the webmail server and to get it running.

Then, remember to correctly configure all your MX and nameservers so that you don't start boucing mail off certain providers.

Comment: Can you please mention some of the available outsources solutions, alternativet to google app webmail?

Comment: Generally, any web-host will offer quite a wide variety of options for personlised email service, almost always with webmail access. You might want to look at a good package solution from www.godaddy.com or similar. You could just hire a pacakge deal with which they host your website AND provide email. In addition, you can start off with a basic deal, and as your website grows you can keep scaling up the solution all the way to a private web server run and maintained by them.

Comment: Ok thanks, I ended up using namecheap's email service, which is free for the first year if you choose it for a single personal account.